# Mazda 3 Sedan 2010 - Replacing trunk light holder

Tags: wiring, mazda-3, trunk

As stated in the title I am trying to figure out a way to pull out the holder from the trunk of my 2010 Mazda 3 Sedan. Adding more to the situation, the holder has melted and is now moved a bit inside, when I tried pulling it off.

I could not find a way to access it from the trunk itself without opening anything?
or should I access it from the rear Windscreen panel, if so how to open it? I have removed the 6 plastic screws from the rear seat (back of the seat) but somehow not able to pull out the panel.

I don't know the exact terms hence posted picture below.[image]

Tried searching everywhere, but could not find anything convincing.

Comment: Could you also post a photo of the holder itself - we might be able to see something...